# Local exponential stability of $x' = Ax + b(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, stability-in-odes

Let us prove that the system $x′ = Ax + b(x)$ where $\|b(x)\| \le C \|x\|^2$
is locally exponentially stable around $0$ if A is diagonal and all elements on the diagonal are real and negative.

**My attempt:**

The solution of the system is given by:

$$x(t)= e^{(t-t_0)A}x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} e^{(t-s)A}b(s) \,ds$$

Thus:

$$\|x(t)\| \le e^{(t-t_0)\|A\|}\|x_0\| + \int_{t_0}^{t} e^{t\|A\|}\|b(s)\| \,ds$$

$$ \le e^{(t-t_0)\|A\|}\|x_0\| + \int_{t_0}^{t} e^{t\|A\|}C\|x(s)\|^2 \,ds  $$

Besides, if we consider the system $y'=Ay$ with the same $A$, we already know that the system is exponentially stable around $0$. I am looking for an expression of the form:

$$ \|x(t)\| \le k\|x_0\|  e^{-\lambda (t-t_0)} $$

for all $\|x_0\|  < c$ with $c, k$ and $\lambda$ positive constants. How can I continue?

**Edit:**

Since matrix $A$ is Hurwitz:

$$ \|e^{(t-t_0)A} x_0\|\le k\|x_0\|  e^{-\lambda (t-t_0)} $$

Hence:

$$\|x(t)\| \le  k  e^{-\lambda (t-t_0)} \|x_0\| + \int_{t_0}^{t} ke^{-\lambda (t-s)} \|x_0\| C \|x(s)\|^2 \,ds$$

$$ e^{\lambda t} \|x(t)\| \le  k  e^{\lambda t_0} \|x_0\| + \int_{t_0}^{t} k  \|x_0\| C e^{\lambda s} \|x(s)\|^2 \,ds$$

We consider $\|x_0\| \le \epsilon$. I was thinking of using Grönwall's inequality but the exponent 2 does not permit this.

Comment: You completely lost that $A$ is negative definite or that all eigenvalues have negative real part.

Comment: Hint. Since $A$ is Hurwitz stable, then $||e^{A(t-t_0)}||\le Me^{-\alpha(t-t_0)}$ for some $M\ge1$ and $\alpha>0$. Use that to derive a better version of the first inequality you got.

Comment: Understood. How can I simplify the $\|x(s)\|^2$ term? Is it true that if $ \|x_0\| \le \epsilon $ then $\|x(t)\| \le \epsilon$ ?